# Formula for getting the Left most cell value from a 'Range of cells'

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regexextract

Need your support in finding a solution for an issue which I am facing now.

[image]

Formula for Column A... Data Range from B to D

- Have values in a range of spreadsheet cells (From column B to D)
- Value may or may not be present within the range
- I need the formula to update the leftmost value from the same row to the Column A.. E.g In Row 2, "Abil" is the leftmost cell from the range B2 to D2.

Something like `=Left(B2:D2)` which will select the leftmost cell value to the A2 cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IF(B2:B<>"", B2:B, C2:C)<>"", 
                 IF(B2:B<>"", B2:B, C2:C), D2:D))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks @user0.. It worked perfectly resolving all my issues!

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(B2:D), , 999^99))), "\w+")))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(B2:D), , 999^99))), " ")), , 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you "User0" ... It worked...

Comment: Only issue which I faced is, in few cells now I am having URLs as the cell value...  
E.g hxxps://webapps.stackexchange.com

@user0 The formula you provided only shows "hxxts" with in the cell triming off the remaining section.. SO how can we get the full value within the cell without checking the value within the cell & trimming text within ?

Comment: @JacksonGilbert answer updated

Comment: The last updated array formula is very much easy and perfect... 

Appreciate your support...